# What is the difference between Angular's httpClient in "@angular/http" and in "@angular/common/http"?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

There are two http client in angular 5 one is in "@angular/http" and another one is in "@angular/common/http". What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use **Angular 4.3.** or higher

- [**Http**](https://angular.io/api/http/Http) and `HttpModule` from the `@angular/http` are deprecated.
- [**HttpClient**](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) and `HttpClientModule` from the `@angular/common/http` are the newer versions.

For differences you can check documentation.